# MLA style: I need help citing an old article I found in a website

Tags: writing, mla

I found this article from Aldous Huxley that was written a long long time ago, this is the only website I found that has it in full. http://csp.org/practices/entheogens/docs/huxley-drugs.html

In my essay I quoted this and sourced it as is here: "The dictatorships of tomorrow will deprive men of their freedom, but will give them in exchange a happiness none the less real, as a subjective experience, for being chemically induced." (Huxley)

But how on earth do I cite in my works cited page. This is what I put for now.:

Huxley, Aldous. "Drugs That Shape Men's Minds." CSP. N.p., 3 Sept. 1999. Web. 19 May 2016.

Would this be the correct way to cite this in my works cited page mla style since Im sourcing the website I found the article and not the article itself from where it came from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about citation styles, which should be asked and answered at [writers.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to cite the original from the Saturday Evening Post in 1958. If you can't get a copy of the original, then you could provide the web site from which you obtained a copy, but you need to provide a URL. It has been republished, so it should not be difficult to read an dependably accurate version (e.g., see [this](https://www.brainpickings.org/2014/03/25/aldous-huxley-moksha-drugs/)).